# C# - Why put a interface generic constraint instead of just passing the interface type?

Tags: c#, generics

I find a lot of code like this:

```
public interface IFoo
{
   void DoSomething();
}

public void RegisterFoos<T>(T foo) where T : IFoo
{
    foo.DoSomething();
}
```

I don't get this kind of code, why not just pass an IFoo?

Comment: One reason may be for flexiblity, if you want to add another innterface constraint, you can add it easily, but if you pass type, you can not add another interface easily

Comment: It prevent boxing for value-types.

Comment: @RezaAghaei - that's a decent point.

Comment: @PetSerAl - are you sure? if I pass a struct that implements the interface, I expect there to be boxing.

Comment: Where did you expect boxing? You does not need boxing to pass parameter, because you pass it as value-type. You does not need boxing to call interface methods, because it is done with [`constrained`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.constrained.aspx) prefix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see at least two reasons.

One reason would be to allow a reference of a specific type to be sent. As an interface you can sent the same object, but you can only use `foo.GetType()` to get the type but that is the actual type of the object. By using a generic type you can cast an object to a different type, and `typeof(T)` gets that type.

Another reason would be to be able to return a reference of the same type as the parameter. Example:

```
public T DoSomething<T>(T foo) where T : IFoo {
  foo.DoSomething();
  return foo;
}
```

Comment: But neither of those appear in the presented code-case :}

Comment: @user2864740: That is correct, but the OP wrote about code *like* that. The presented code is an obvious example.

Comment: your return statement has made me realize the value here. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By using generic constraints you have more flexibility.

Consider:

```
public class Foo:IFoo
{
    public void DoSomething() // from interface
    {
    }

    public void DoSomethingWithFoo() // custom method
    {
    }
}
```

And now the two versions of the method:

```
public void RegisterFoosGeneric<T>(T item, Action<T> action) where T : IFoo
{
    action(item);
}

public void RegisterFoos(IFoo item, Action<IFoo> action)
{
    action(item);
}
```

This line is valid:

```
test.RegisterFoosGeneric(new Foo(), x=>x.DoSomethingWithFoo());
```

This one is not, giving a compile error:

```
test.RegisterFoos(new Foo1(), x=>x.DoSomethingWithFoo1());
```